# Multiple inheritance from library in C++ with ambiguity

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Let's say I have the following situation

```
// in library
class A {
    void foo();
}

class B: public A {}

// own program
class MyBaseClass: public A {}

class MyTypicalClass: public MyBaseClass {}

class SpecialCaseClass: public virtual MyBaseClass, public virtual B {}
```

Usually I don't need features defined in `B` and it comes with some overhead I want to avoid in `MyTypicalClass`. For the `SpecialCaseClass` I want properties defined in `MyBaseClass` and in `B`. I get the error: *error: request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous*, because I inherit from `A` twice. Is there an elegant way I can take everything ambiguous from `B`'s `A` instead of the `A` of `MyBaseClass`?

Comment: "Usually I don't need features defined in B and it comes with some overhead I want"  - so why are you inheriting from `B` instead of composing it? You should not use inheritance for "convenience" or to bring members into scope, only use inheritance to represent an "is" relationship, not a "has" relationship. You also don't need to use inheritance in C++ for implicit conversions as you can define implicit-conversions separately: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: Also composition is a better way if you only need only few methods of B, instead of forwarding all the available methods

Comment: `virtual MyBaseClass` `public virtual B` doesn't mean that `A` inheritance will be shared. You need two `public virtual A` to achieve that. Randomly adding `virtual` into inheritance lists is a bad approach.